# When consuming data from a REST API, is it better to generate a data class or just a simple normal class?

Tags: kotlin

Assume that I have an API which will return me a response about user information:

- name
- age

In normal class, I will create a UserInfo class:

```
class UserInfo (val username:String, val age:String)
```

But I found a lot of people who suggested that it should be a data class (and part of them suggested it MUST BE):

```
data class UserInfo (val username:String, val age:String)
```

AFAIK, no matter UserInfo is a data class or not, it is **public final** by default, it auto-generates getter function of the properties which are also **public final** by default and the properties cannot be assigned with any value.

I know the **data class** auto-generates/overrides useful functions like **copy()**, **toString()** and **equals()**. If I only need to get the name and age values of the UserInfo class and there is no need to compare the equality of UserInfo, do I still need to declare it as a data class?

Comment: I would say it's better to declare it as a data class. If it were not, people who would look at your code later could easily assume that it's a data class. That could cause problems if they change the code in a way that requires a proper equals or hashcode method.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Can you give a scenario or explain it in a more detail way?

Comment: Well, let's say someone tries to compare two `UserInfo` objects with `userInfo1 == userInfo2`. If `UserInfo` is not a data class, this would always return false unless `userInfo1` refers to the exact same object as `userInfo2`. When it's a data class, that code would instead check equality of `username` and `age`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on context that you gave, `UserInfo` class should be declared as data class.

Role of data classes is to only hold data needed to represent that structure, without having any behavior, and that is exactly what you have with `UserInfo`, you only want to hold that data. That doesn't mean that you are obligated in any way to use data class, but it would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest using a data class. 
Without having `hashCode` and `equals` properly specified, you cannot safely use `UserInfo` in Collections.

Comment: If I have no collections, do I still need it?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. But can you really be sure that you'll never use a collection?